# React: Pass data from a component back to App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to pass User information from a child component to App.js as we have a user icon within the App.js itself

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import './App.css';
// routes
import Router from './routes';
//import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import AccountCircle from '@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';

function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const tUserInfo = ['AAAAA', 12345];
  
  const showUserInfo = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleUserInfoClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <img src={logo} className="photo" alt="logo" />
          <Typography variant="h6" component="div" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <b>Transport Feedback App</b>
          </Typography>
            <div>
              <IconButton
                size="large"
                aria-label="account of current user"
                aria-controls="menu-appbar"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                color="inherit"
                onClick={showUserInfo}
                float='left'
              >
                <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                keepMounted
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                onClose={handleUserInfoClose}
              >
                {tUserInfo.map((userinfo) => (
                  <MenuItem disabled
                    key={userinfo}
                    value={userinfo}
                  >
                  {userinfo}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <br/>
      <header className="App-header">
      <HelmetProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Router />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </HelmetProvider>
      </header>
    </div> 
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a hardcoded value for **tUserInfo** in the above App.js file. I need to get that details dynamically from a child component.

**Router.js**

```
import { Navigate, useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './pages/login';

export default function Router() {
  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: '/',
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/login" />, index: true },
        { path: 'login', element: <LoginPage /> }
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <LoginPage />,
    },
  ]);

  return routes;
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import { useNavigate  } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function SignIn() {
  const [loginErrorText, setloginErrorText] = React.useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const payload = {
      employee_id: data.get('empid')
    }

    setisLoading(true);
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'user_login',
      data: payload, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }, 
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.data.status === 200){
        //navigate("/home");
      }
      else{
        setloginErrorText(response.data.message)
      }
    }).catch(function (error){
        console.log(error);
    });
  };

    return (
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
        <Box
          sx={{
            boxShadow: 3,
            borderRadius: 2,
            px: 4,
            py: 6,
            marginTop: 8,
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Typography style={{color: 'black'}} component="h1" variant="h5">
            Sign in
          </Typography>
          <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
            <TextField
              margin="normal"
              required
              fullWidth
              id="empid"
              label="Employee ID"
              name="empid"
              inputProps={{ maxLength: 7 }}  
              helperText={loginErrorText}
              autoFocus
            />
            <Button
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
              variant="contained"
              sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}> Sign In </Button>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    );
}
```

I will get user info in my axios call in **login.js**.

Is there a way to pass it to **tUserInfo** in **App.js** ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This is a big issue with react library (prop drilling). One solution is to perform the api call in app. component according to your code, which is not wise. Your component seperation is no correct. Usually App.js will not have any state or anything. Other and best solution is to use Context api from react. to perform login. That way user info can be accessed anywhere without have to pass data to and from child.

Comment: You could just export an object that stores the userInfo in `login.js` ->  `export const userInfo = {}`  ,   inside your login -> `Object.assign(userInfo, response)`,  you can then import `import {userInfo} from "./login.js"`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function from App.js to the child component and from child component call that function and update the value in that function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).